# prevent memory errors while comparing two files in python

Tags: python

I searched for a solution to compare two files in python and i stumbled on the code shared below which actually works except that it gives me a memory error. This is because the script reads in the entire file and does the comparison. I need a script that does the same without so much effect on memory. The original code is below:

```
with open('ip1.txt', 'r') as file1:
with open('ip2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    file1_unique = set(file1)
    same = file1_unique.intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('match_ips.txt', 'w') as file_out:
for line in same:
    file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: You need a script that does the same. Have you considered making some changes to the code you've found? What are you stuck at? Remember that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service - we don't write code for you, usually people here help or point out errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, reading the whole file in memory is the problem. So how do you change it so that you don't read the whole file yet be able to compare them? Is it possible?

Well it depends, one solution depends on if the files are sorted or if they can be sorted first (hint: unix sort command).

If the two files are sorted, you can compare the files line by line (tip: you can also use the unix: diff command)

```
def adv(gen):
  try:
    v = next(gen)
  except StopIteration:
    v = None
  return None

with open('a.txt') as f1:
  with open('b.txt') as f2:
    a = adv(f1)
    b = adv(f2)
    while (a,b) != (None, None):
      if b is None or a < b:
        print(a)
        a = adv(f1)
      elif a is None or b > a:
        print(b)
        b = adv(f2)
      else:
        # the lines are the same, advance both files
        a = adv(f1)
        b = adv(f2)
```

Comment: thanks Pykler, i am very new to python programming. Does the code here help sort the file or compare both? Please add more comments so i can have a better understanding.